# Give color to the line plot according to the third variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot

I am trying to plot the line plots using for loop, I am giving the overview of my code structure here

```py
epi_dist=[]
for file in glob.glob('*extension'):  
    dist=file.distn()
    epi_dist.append(dist)
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i  in range(1,1000,2):
        a,b=function(file,i)
        x.append(a)
        y.append(b)
        
    plt.plot(x,y,c=epi_dist)

plt.show()
```

I wanted to give the color for the line plot according to the variable `epi_dist`.
`x` and `y` have the identical number of values.

Looking forward to your valuable suggestions

Comment: Is the missing `'` a typo?

Comment: Is this helping?  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html

Comment: In my case each line plot have a single color but different line plot's color will be different according to third variable